# populate ListBox with groups in code-behind to ListBox using jquery chosen

Tags: c#, jquery, listbox

I am writing a web application using web forms (ASP.NET / C#). I have a ListBox Control that is using the jquery plugin, chosen.  I populate the list box in the code-behind using a database call.  It is working fine so I wanted to add groups to the ListBox.  The data is displayed in a list, not by the groups I set.
I beleive the problem is with the chosen query plugin.  I need to maybe set the option of this plugin somehow but I have not seen any documentation on how to do it.
This is my javascript / HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".chosen-select").chosen({
             search_contains: true,
             no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!",
             allow_single_deselect: true
         });
         $('.chosen-container').css('width', '600px');
     });
</script>
 <asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxTo" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    data-placeholder="Choose recipient(s)…" multiple="true" class="chosen-select">
        </asp:ListBox>
```

This is my C# code to populate the ListBox:

```
foreach (DataRow row in m_dtRecipients.Rows)
{
     ListItem recItem = new ListItem(row["Name"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString());
     if (row["UserID"].ToString().Equals("Global"))
     {
         recItem.Attributes[OPT_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE] = GLOBAL_GROUP;
     }
     else if (row["UserID"].ToString().Equals(m_strUserID))
     {
         recItem.Attributes[OPT_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE] = PERSONAL_GROUP;
     }
     else
     {
         recItem.Attributes[OPT_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE] = INDIVIDUAL_GROUP;
     }
     lstBoxTo.Items.Add(recItem);
}
```

The data is correct and the ListBox shows the data but not in groups.
How do I get the chosen jquery plugin to show the data in groups?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have learned that the ListBox and DropDownList do not support optgroup.  So I wanted to try this solution but am having trouble understanding the javascript.
In the code behind, attributes are added to each ListItem:

```
foreach (ListItem item in ((DropDownList)sender).Items)
        {
            if (System.Int32.Parse(item.Value) < 5)
                item.Attributes.Add("classification", "LessThanFive");
            else
                item.Attributes.Add("classification", "GreaterThanFive");

        }
```

This is the javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Create groups for dropdown list
        $("select.listsmall option[@classification='LessThanFive']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Less than five'>");
        $("select.listsmall option[@classification='GreaterThanFive']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Greater than five'>"); 
    });
```

I don't understand where the "select.listsmall' represents.  I tried using my ListBox ID but I get an exception.
Can anyone explain this part of the javascript?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
THis is how I am using the code-behind and javascript from above:

```
private const string OPT_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE = "grouping";
private const string GLOBAL_GROUP = "Global Groups";
private const string PERSONAL_GROUP = "Personal Groups";
private const string INDIVIDUAL_GROUP = "Individuals";

    foreach (DataRow row in m_dtRecipients.Rows)
    {
     ListItem recItem = new ListItem(row["Name"].ToString(), row["ID"].ToString());
     if (row["UserID"].ToString().Equals("Global"))
     {
        recItem.Attributes.Add(OPT_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE, GLOBAL_GROUP);                          
     }
     else if (row["UserID"].ToString().Equals(m_strUserID))
     {
        recItem.Attributes.Add(OPT_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE, PERSONAL_GROUP);                     
     }
     else
     {
        recItem.Attributes.Add(OPT_GROUP_ATTRIBUTE, INDIVIDUAL_GROUP);
     }
     lstBoxTo.Items.Add(recItem);
    }
```

This is the ListBox HTML:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxTo" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
  data-placeholder="Choose recipient(s)…" multiple="true" class="chosen-select">
</asp:ListBox>
```

This is the javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".chosen-select").chosen({
                 search_contains: true,
                 no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!",
                 allow_single_deselect: true,
                 group: true
             });
             $('.chosen-container').css('width', '600px');

             //Create groups for dropdown list
             $("select.chosen-select option[@grouping='Global Groups']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Global Groups'>");
             $("select.chosen-select option[@grouping='Personal Groups']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Personal Groups'>");
             $("select.chosen-select option[@grouping='Individuals']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Individuals'>");
         });
```

Is there something that I am missing or wrong?

**UPDATE**
Well, if I remove the '@' from the attribute=value, it does not throw an exception but it also does not group the list.

Comment: listsmall is a css class on your listbox. The way it is written it is needed for jQuery to find your select list (listbox) in HTML. Add 'listsmall' to your listbox and it should find it.

Comment: I have a css class defined for my listbox as 'chosen-select'. I tried using 'select.chosen-select' in place of 'select.listsmall'. I still get 'unrecognized expression error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem...the chosen-jquery configuration function has to come after the 'wrapAll' functions.  This is the change:

```
$(document).ready(function () {       
        //Create groups for dropdown list
        $(".chosen-select option[grouping='GlobalGroups']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Global Groups'>");
        $(".chosen-select option[grouping='PersonalGroups']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Personal Groups'>");
        $(".chosen-select option[grouping='Individuals']").wrapAll("<optgroup label='Individuals'>");

        //Configure the ListBox using the 'chosen' jquery plugin
        $(".chosen-select").chosen({
            search_contains: true,
            no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!",
            allow_single_deselect: true
        });
        $('.chosen-container').css('width', '600px');
    });
```